# extjs store.getById() fails

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm trying to get an Associated Model (E.g. groups and associated users) from a store with:

```
Ext.each(this.getView().getSelection()[0].getAssociatedData().users,function(element){
     var theuser = myStore.getById(element.id);
     theuser.set('deactivated','true');
}
```

This works for the first 25 Users (id 1-25) however the store is filtered through a pagination plugin. In reason of the filtering with offset and limit the requested id isn't in the local store.

any idea on how to force the store to get the model from remote in case the id isn't available in the local cache?
Or is it anyhow possible to use the data from getAssociatedData, change something and write the record back through the writer proxy?

thx, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: you mean by filtering - you haven't even loaded the complete store to the client due to paging reasons or something like that? or you filtered it local only? usually the getById fn is not effected by filters.

Comment: it is filtered by the paging plugin remotely (?page=1&start=0&limit=0)

Comment: edited the question trying to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

The store's getById() method will only return the locally-available records.

If you want to retrieve a model, and you know the id already, you can simply do `<model class>.load(id)`. (If the model is unknown, you can do `myStore.getModel().load(id)`

Note that the load method returns immediately, but it returns a stub - you'll want to use a callback to process the change to the `deactivated` field.

In ExtJS5, the Session support will help ensure that the models referred to in both the association store and your `myStore` object refer to the same model instance.

Comment: As [per the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load), you can provide a callback by `load(id, { success: callbackFn })`

Comment: Is the load success function get the loaded record as Parameter?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in the documentation in the link I gave in my last comment.